# Integration $u-$substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration

When we solve the following integral

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \Big ( \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \Big )^{2} dx,$$

we make the substitution $u = \ln(x)$, $du = \frac{dx}{x}$. And then the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{2} e^{-u}du.$$

How does the term $e^{-u}$ appear in the integral?

Comment: Because $x=e^u$...

Comment: Oh ... sometimes trivialities are the hardest things ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u=\ln{x}$ then $x \; du =dx$ and $x=e^u$.  Putting this together yields $$\int_1^{\infty} \left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\right)^2 \; \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{u}{e^u}\right)^2 \; e^u\mathrm{d}u=\int_0^{\infty} u^2e^{-u} \; \mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: Yes thank you. I just forgot that $e^{\ln(x)} = x$ ...